# Can we set unlimited maxFiles in winston?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

we have implemented logic using nodejs if existing file in directory more than 30 days delete the file so we dont want to winston set `maxFiles` because we want to keep files based on time .

My second question related to winston is when we rotate file currently its appending server1.log once it reach file size , is it possible to append with date e.g `server-03-10-2017.log` ?

ctrl.js

```
   var logger = new(winston.Logger)({
      level: null,
      transports: [
//          new(winston.transports.Console)({formatter}),
          new(winston.transports.File)({
            filename: './logs/dit/server.log',
            maxsize: 1024 * 1024 * 20, // 15MB
            timestamp: true,
            maxFiles: 10,
            json: false,
            formatter: function (options) {
             return options.message;
            }
        })
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the dynamic naming you can have a look at the rotationFormat, but rotating file is needed...

```
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { 
  filename: './logs/dit/server.log',
  maxsize: 1024 * 1024 * 20, // 15MB
  rotationFormat: function() {
    return getFormattedDate();
    function getFormattedDate() {
      var temp = new Date();
      return dateStr = padStr(temp.getFullYear()) +
      padStr(1 + temp.getMonth()) +
      padStr(temp.getDate()) +
      padStr(temp.getHours()) +
      padStr(temp.getMinutes()) +
      padStr(temp.getSeconds());
    }
    function padStr(i) {
      return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : "" + i;
    }
  }
});
```

output file should look something like ./logs/dit/server2010310173556.log

padStr needed to pad with "0" if it's a single digit.

Github pull request [article](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/pull/273)

EDIT : You should set `maxsize` and specify `rotationFormat` function that return a formated date (Need to modify lib/winston/transports/file.js accordingly see article). It will be append at the end of the filename. I'm not sure  `maxFiles` is needed

Comment: I can not open url `article` not authorized , what i understand we have to set  `maxFiles` in winston , it is required attribute ?

Comment: How we invoke `rotationFormat` method ?